# Dynamics 365 API - Action AddMembersTeam

Tags: python, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am using the API to add multiple users to a team in Dynamics. I have got the code working when I want to add a single users but I need it to work with adding a list of users.

I am using Python to make these calls.

[Here is the documentation I am going off of in Dynamics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/addmembersteam?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Here is part of my code:

```
        append_team_url = f"{BASE_DATA_URL}teams({team_guid})/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddMembersTeam"
    team_data = {
                    "Members": [
                        {
                            "ownerid": users_add
                        }
                    ]
                }
    append_users_response = requests.post(append_team_url, headers=api_headers_no_return, data=json.dumps(team_data))
```

users_add is a list of GUID's:

```
['85927c2e-52e6-e511-80e7-0050569e0d14', 'ebb0ec50-733f-e811-a964-000d3a34edeb',
```

'd3d6ec34-df57-e511-80e4-0050569e44e8', '19452bf7-3b57-e511-80e4-0050569e44e8']

The error I get:

> An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.Json.JsonReaderExtensions.ValidateNodeType(IJsonReader jsonReader, JsonNodeType expectedNodeType)\r\n

Any help would be much appreciated!

I know I can just make the call in a loop in Python but based on the wording of the documentation it seems like it's possible to pass multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload should look like this, look at the Json array of users. [Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/271706/create-user-and-team-relationship-in-dynamics-crm-with-api-call/771430)

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/teams(team-guid-id)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddMembersTeam HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{
"Members": [{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser",
"ownerid": "85927c2e-52e6-e511-80e7-0050569e0d14"
},{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser",
"ownerid": "ebb0ec50-733f-e811-a964-000d3a34edeb"
}]
}
```