# How to add/remove member to a team in CRM dynamics using HTTPClient in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, dynamics-crm-online

I see the code to add member to team using the class AddMembersTeamRequest. But
how to add member to a team HTTPClient in web API C#.

I have tried using the uri

```
/api/data/v9.2/teams('{teamid}')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddMembersTeam
```

but I get the error 'error in query syntax'.

how to pass the userids in the content?

Comment: The error complains about the URL, not the library you used to make the call. You'd get the same error if you used curl or POSTMAN

Answer (score 0):

Pleas look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65746179/5616374

Besides, you can perform the `AddTeamMember` with `AddMembersTeamRequest` which should look like this:

```
public static void AddMembersToTeam(Guid teamId, Guid[] membersId, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            // Create the AddMembersTeamRequest object.
            AddMembersTeamRequest addRequest = new AddMembersTeamRequest();

            // Set the AddMembersTeamRequest TeamID property to the object ID of 
            // an existing team.
            addRequest.TeamId = teamId;

            // Set the AddMembersTeamRequest MemberIds property to an 
            // array of GUIDs that contains the object IDs of one or more system users.
            addRequest.MemberIds = membersId;

            // Execute the request.
            service.Execute(addRequest);
        }
```

Hope it will be helpful.